# What are Deis Workflow Alternatives?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, orchestration, platform-as-a-service

We're looking to build an internal Heroku-like PaaS that supports clustering and a DFS. We found Deis Workflow that seems to do exactly what we're looking for, but the project has since been discontinued.

Are there any alternatives that are similar to Deis Workflow that achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the README of the deis/workflow project on GitHub](https://github.com/deis/workflow), it is no longer maintained since March 1, 2018.

However, the README indicates that there is a fork, called [Hephy Workflow](https://github.com/teamhephy/workflow). At the time of writing, this is the first time I heard about Deis and Hephy and I have not worked with these solutions.

Alternatives to these products are OpenShift, Google App, AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Azure App Service, Cloud Foundry, Apollo according to [StackShare](https://stackshare.io/deis-workflow/alternatives).

You mentioned that you are looking to build something **internal**. This would probably mean that native-PAAS like AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Azure App Service and Google App are not an option as these are only available on their platform.

One of the options could be OpenShift. This product has an enterprise and open-source version that can be installed on your on-premise or cloud servers. You could also decide to create a bunch of VMs on Google Cloud and install OpenShift on these servers.

Answer (score 0):

[Jelastic](https://jelastic.com/) is definitely a good [multi-cloud alternative PaaS](https://jelastic.com/blog/forrester-listed-jelastic-among-major-public-cloud-platforms/) to Heroku, OpenShift, CloudFoundry and others. The platform providers [auto-clustering](https://docs.jelastic.com/auto-clustering) for multiple software stacks (app server and DBs) and supports [different file storage](https://jelastic.com/software-defined-storage/) options. In general, Jelastic project has two main pillars:

1. The automation software platform which can be [installed on top of any infrastructure](https://jelastic.com/enterprise-paas/#multi-cloud)
2. [The wide network of public cloud providers](https://jelastic.cloud/) that offer managed Jelastic PaaS with [pay-per-use](https://docs.jelastic.com/pricing-model) model

There is a variety of [use cases and white-papers](https://jelastic.com/whitepapers/) with end users stories.

Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of Jelastic project.